# I can't understand why and how are we passing something to this function. Selector question

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It doesn't appear that in the selectCartItemsCount we pass something, yet it somehow knows how to set selectCart

```
 -----------------------SELECTOR--------------------------
    const selectCart = state => state.cart;

    export const selectCartItems = createSelector(
        [selectCart],
        (cart) => cart.cartItems);

    export const selectCartItemsCount = createSelector(
        [selectCartItems],
        cartItems =>
        //non serve fare accomulator = ...
        //perchè lo fai lui automaticamente la dentro
        cartItems.reduce((accomulator, currentItem) => (
            accomulator + currentItem.quantity
        ), 0)
    )

    --------------------------CART ICON-----------------------------
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return ({
            itemCount: selectCartItemsCount(state)
        })
    }
```

Comment: adding note that i am using the reselect library: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use`selectors` so that we have the ability to take the returned object from the first argument as the input to the second argument. So, it knows the state that it is being passed (in a tree-like fashion,with only the state that it needs)

```
 import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect'
 const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
     itemCount: selectCartItemsCount
})
```

Comment: yes I see that it is structured like a tree, but how do I pass that state in the first place? In mapStateToProps i pass him the state but I have no idea how it handles the  const selectCart = state => state.cart;

Comment: saw that one and really simplifies the whole structure, thank you very much!